# A game with $n+1$ players and a price $\textbf{B}$

Tags: probability

In a game with $n+1$ players, who each player has, independently, $p$ chance to win. The winners share a price **B**. Let's **A** be a player and **X** the gain of **A**.

**EDIT 01** : If two players win, each player gain $B/2$.

$(1)$ What's the expected total gain shared by the players.

$(2)$ Demonstrate that
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

$(3)$ Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$ by conditionning on the fact that **A** win or lose and deduce that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[(1+\textbf{B})^{-1}\right]=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{(n+1)p}$$

---

**EDIT 02** :
With the help of this community, I come up with the answer to $(1)$,
$$\begin{align} 
\mathbb{E}[Y_n] &=0 \cdot \mathbb{P}\left\{Y_n \mid n=0\right\} + B (1-\mathbb{P}\left\{Y_n \mid n=0\right\}) \\
&= B(1-p)^{n+1}
\end{align}$$
where $Y_n$ is the gain won by $n$ winners.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a factor of $\mathbf B$ missing in the displayed equation in ($2$).

Comment: I thought the same thing but I copied the question correctly.

Comment: Well it's clear that the expected gain of any player will double if the prize being shared is doubled, so whatever you copied the question from is in error.

Comment: **Hint**: (1) let $ Y $ denote the total gain of all players. It can only take two values, what's the probability of $ Y $ taking both of them?

Comment: @joriki Is my **EDIT** fix our problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It was already sufficiently clear before your edit that "share" a prize" was meant to imply "share a prize in equal parts". That doesn't change the fact that the expected gain per player is obviously proportional to the prize being shared.

Comment: @joriki Ok. If we ignore $(2)$, can you help me to understand $(1)$ and $(3)$?

Comment: @Jytug I don't understand. If we let $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i$. How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}[ Y]$?

Comment: @hlapointe: The point of Jytug's hint was that that's not the best way to look at the problem. The point of view adopted in the hint is more fruitful.

Comment: @joriki Ok, I got it. Let me 5 minutes to write it down. Can you help me to do the $(3)$.

Comment: (3) doesn't make any sense -- it takes the expectation of the non-random quantity $\mathbf B$.

Comment: So I'm not crazy. :D